# Mockito/PowerMockito mocking private factory method

Tags: java, mockito, private, factory-method

I want to use pattern 1 suggested in the following link:
https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation
 and have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private AnyType anyObject;
  private Foo foo; // Foo is a thirdparty class

  public MyClass(AnyType anyObject) {
    //...
    foo = makeFoo();
  }

  private Foo makeFoo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a test as follows:

```
@Test
public void myTestMethod() {
  MyClass myClass = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());

  // now i want to do something like this:
  Foo mockFoo= Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
  // Mockito.doReturn(mockFoo).when(myClass).makeFoo());
}
```

The problem is my factory method makeFoo is a private method, so I can't access it. I don't want to make it public just for the test. My test classes are not in the same package as my productive code either, so making it visible only for the package won't work.

Update:
Now i found another problem. Assumed that makeFoo() is public, 'mockFoo' will not be returned either, yet the real makeFoo() method is invoked. This happens since the invocation of makeFoo() (in the constructor of MyClass) is prior to the creation of mockFoo.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or am I doing something totally wrongly?

Thanks you guys in advance for helping!!

Comment: Is it not a feasible compromise to put it to package protected? Not nice, but at least accessible...

Comment: @ppeterka66: as I wrote above, my test classes are not in the same package as my productive code. So it won't work :(

Comment: Sorry, somehow my eyes skipped that part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `whenNew` of PowerMockito. This allows to "overwrite" the constructor call of an object and return a mock of it instead.

http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew%28java.lang.Class%29

http://www.gitshah.com/2010/05/how-to-mock-constructors-using.html

Comment: yes, i found out about PowerMockito.whenNew yesterday. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to set a field inside your class, it's doable with [`MockitoAnnotations`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)

You just need to create fields you need, annotate them and in unit test before section call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`

In your case it will look like:

```
 @Spy
 @InjectMocks
 MyClass myClass;
 @Mock
 Foo foo;

 @Before
 public void initMocks() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }
```

Please read also documentation above.

Comment: I tried out your solution but the real method makeFoo() is called to create a real Foo. As i understand, the @Mock notation just create a stub for the parameters that you give to your class.

Comment: And it should also set it to annotated with `@InjectMock` object. But if you don't want makeFoo be called, may be it would be a good idea to separate Foo creation and `MyClass`.

Comment: are you talking of the FactoryHelper pattern described in the link above? Btw, InjectMock is not easy to use for me, since the paramter AnyType of MyClass is again has to be stubbed and there are some method invocations which have to be mocked to, so it doesn't work with just a Mock annotation :(